# \newcommand - Missing \begin{document}

Tags: macros

On defining a new command, and using it, LaTeX throws an error that `Missing \begin{document}`. What is the issue here?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcommand{details}[2]{
#1 \hspace{2cm} : #2
}
\begin{document}
\details{name}{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean `\newcommand{\details}[2]{....}` ;-)